# ebean run ddl only if the database does not exist

Tags: java, ddl, ebean

If I have `ddl.generate` and `ddl.run` set to `true`, it always drop my database when I restart the app.

If I add the `ddl.createOnly=true`, it will throw out an exception when I create the ebean server instance.

Question:

Is there anyway for me to say "please create the database if it does not exist, or don't do anything if database is already created"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please create the database if it does not exist

No there is not.

Answer (score 2):

Both ie. ddl.generate and ddl.run  when set to true will first drop the DDL.
But when you set ddl.generate to false and ddl.run to true, then it will first drop the DDL and then create the DDL, which results in update of a database if any new table is added in database.

Reference:You can see https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/dbmigration/DdlGenerator.html

Answer (score 1):

As a bit of a workaround, you can wrap your EbeanServerFactory.create() call in a try-catch block like so

```
ServerConfig serverConfig = new ServerConfig();
serverConfig.setName("mydb");

// ddl.generate, ddl.createOnly and ddl.run should be set to true in
// your ebean.properties file(if using one) else set them
// programmatically
serverConfig.loadFromProperties();

try {
    server = EbeanServerFactory.create(ebeanConfig);
} catch(Exception e) {
    ebeanConfig.setDdlRun(false);
    server = EbeanServerFactory.create(ebeanConfig);
}
```

It would be nicer to be able to say createIfNotExists=true, but this works in the meantime.

Comment: Glad I could help!